# tinymce set cursor position to empty span

Tags: tinymce

I have an empty span and I would like to set cursor position on it. My codes works in Edge, Chrome, FireFox but not for IE.

I have tried [set cursor on empty tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464824/set-cursor-on-empty-tag) but the solution is not applicable for me.

This is the sample empty span:

```
<span id="ABC"></span>
```

My codes to set cursor position:

```
ed.on("focus", function (e) {
   ed.focus();
   var node= ed.dom.select("span#ABC");
   ed.selection.setCursorLocation(node[0], 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The technique we use in the editor is adding a zero-width character (`"\uFFEF"` in JS) into the span and selecting *that*. It's a fairly reliable cross-browser way to put the cursor in places the browser doesn't normally support.

These characters are stripped when the content is serialised so there's no impact on the output HTML.